# Equation for a shape formed by fix point on a string tethered at both ends

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Suppose one has a string of length L, one end P0 fixed at -B/2, the other P1 fixed at B/2 (B < L).  If it's more convenient, the ends of the string can be fixed at zero and B

For some FIXED point A on the string, what is the equation of the shape created if **A** is pushed to its extremes and rotated in all directions?  i.e. What is the equation of the path of **A**, which bounds the possible locations of **A**?

NOTE:  This is similar to — but NOT the same as — an ellipse, since the point **A** is fixed on the string, and I am interested in TWO parameterized curves.

**MOTIVATION:**  I am exploring the joint distribution of distances on a string modeled as scaled jointly dirichlet random variables.  If $X_{ij}$ is $Beta(\alpha_{ij},\beta_{ij})$, and $\ell_{ij}$ is the length of the string connecting point $i$ to point $j$, then $D_{ij}=\ell_{ij}X_{ij}$.

Put another way, if $\vec{x}$ ~ $Beta(\vec{\alpha},\vec{\beta})$ and $L$ is a diagonal matrix $\{\ell_{ij}\}_{i<j}$, then my random vector of distances are $D=L\vec{X}$.

Clearly, the set of possible distances of P0 to A and the distances of P1 to A depend heavily on the distance of P0 to P1, so I am interested in incorporating this covariance structure into my parameterization.

Comment: Suppose the lengths of the two parts of the string are $L_0$ and $L_1$. Then the region that $A$ can reach is the intersection of two disks, one centered at $P_0$ with radius $L_0$, and one at $P_1$ with radius $L_1$.